# Contractor cut into the I-Joist flange!

Tags: bathroom, structural, joists, remodeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello.  We are in the middle of bathroom remodel and our contractor cut into the top part of I-flange while removing the subfloor.  He cut diagonally in several places and horizontally on another beam.  They are about 1" deep at the worst part.  The horizontal cut is hard to see but it's along the line where subfloor was cut.

I'm so aggravated because this was easily avoidable if he was playing attention.(the guy who did it is the helper and not the main contractor)

There will be a free standing tub weighing about 100 lbs where the cuts are.

What should I expect in terms of repairing this mess?  Do I need to push to have a structural engineer look and give recommendation or am I overreacting?  The main contractor will be here tomorrow morning to check it out.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your average tub will weigh **a lot more** when full of water (at 8 lbs/gallon) and a person. Is your contractor insured?

Comment: No you are not over reacting, it is a total screw up job.

Comment: Yes the contractor is insured.

Comment: That's good. The good news here is that the top flange is under compression, which makes it easier to repair, but I'd contact the technical support folks at your I-joist manufacturer for a start. They, more than anyone else, would know best if and how that can be repaired, short of wholesale replacement - or that wholesale replacement is required - which is where the contractor's insurance comes into mattering. Those are some deep cuts.

Comment: I tried looking for product marking on the joist but could not find any.  My house is about 25 years old.  Not sure if I can find this out.

Comment: ok I finally found marking in the basement.  From the logo, it looks to be a Trus Product?

Comment: Weyerhaeuser silent floor.

Comment: And yes, your contractor owes you some serious fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cut into the top plate of TGIs... a really bad thing to do. The depth of the cut is really troubling...somebody was being really careless or unskilled. That weakens them substantially.  Had it been just a 1/4" or so, it'd be OK.  But he cut nearly all the way thru the top part.

To fix it, the contractor would need to pull back more flooring and sister on some boards with both glue and screws for a reasonable length to shore that mess up. BOTH SIDES of the TGI.

What they did is inexcusable and need to repaired with a very robust fix.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  My question is how do I ensure that the repair is done correctly or that it can be repaired?  I did contact the manufacturer and hopefully they can give some guidance but not sure if that'll come quickly or at all.

Comment: Maybe others like isherwood who has good framing experience could chime in ,  I'm not much of a framer,   but I would think that 2x4s at least 36" long glued and screwed to both sides of the TGIs would suffice. The contractor will need to remove more flooring to get access, but sub-floor is easy to replace, hopefully he doesn't do more damage cutting the sub-floor which would be like pouring salt on the wound!

Comment: The contractor should find the proper fix for it, not the homeowner, but the homeowner needs to be informed as well. I have seen fixes for this along the lines of adding 2X material that will fill from top to bottom cord, 4 ft long to 8' long or 3/4" plywood filling the web too. Both "infills" (2X or plywood) leaving a 1/8" gap, and glued in place with ails or screws laminating everything together.

Comment: @AT, your contractor needs to talk to Weyerhaeuser to ask _them_ what the proper fix is. _You_ need to talk to them too, in order to ensure you know what is supposed to be done and make sure your contractor is doing it properly. The manager/owner of the company may come in and do a 100% job and give the worker a good talking to or even fire him over this, or, that worker may be an indicator of the way the contractor works in general. The only way for you to be sure is to know what should happen and make sure that it does.

Comment: @FreeMan  While in principle I tend to agree with you, but once the contractor (or his employees) have F'd up  I don't trust them to come up with a proper fix. Many would low-ball a half ass fix bc it's obviously not something they could bill for.   Several times I've had to tell contractors: "This is what you did wrong and this is how you're going to fix it if you want to get paid".

Comment: Which is why I advised the OP to make sure _he_ also understands, from the manufacturer, what the fix should be. That will allow him to ensure it's being taken care of properly. (And why I gave a +1 on your answer.)